# JSoup How to get all the responses

Tags: java, jsoup, headless-browser

Hello I've been trying to automate the monitoring of a site, but it "responses" with multiple documents, I'd like to know how to browse them or select which one I want to parse.

Code is pretty simple:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(urls).execute();
String JSESSIONID = response.cookie("JSESSIONID");
System.out.println(response.cookies());

Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url)
.data(data);
con.post();
System.out.println(con.response().statusCode());
Document document = con.post();
System.out.println(document);
```

The site "responses" like this:

It wont let me post images but here's the link:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxpKY.png]

How to select a different document rather than the first one?

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting here. Jsoup is not a browser, it is parser. Is your job to tell Jsoup which document you want to parse. You can let jsoup follow redirections, but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Exactly that's what I want, how to tell Jsoup to parse "mail/" for example.

Comment: The problem is that follow redirections don't help me here because it ends up in a "document" saying that browser doesn't suppotr javascript. And the documents I need are dinamically generated with javascript, one cache version and another one non-cache.

Comment: And what is `mail/` referring to? How should Jsoup know it? Do you know its full URL, or maybe you want Jsoup to get it (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls)?

Comment: Then I suspect you can't use Jsoup here. Try with Selenium which purpose is to emulate browsers which includes JavaScript support.

Comment: Thank you! your question "How should Jsoup know it, make me review the  document and it contains a javascript file source that has exactly the information I need. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> the documents I need are dinamically generated with javascript

Jsoup is an HTML parser. It doesn't support Javascript. Instead use tools like **Selenium** or **ui4j**.